# nextElementSibling not capturing CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a button that is supposed to open/close a collapsible `div` and the HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class='outer-collapsible'>
  <button type='button' class='collapsible'>Targets and Victims</button>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I select all `button` with the `collapsible` class, I'm trying to use `nextElementSibling` to select `<div class='content'>` like this:

```js
let collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');

for (let i = 0; i < collapsibles.length; i++) {
  if (collapsibles[i].nextElementSibling.style.display == 'block') {
    // do something
  }
}
```

but although `nextElementSibling` is selecting the `div`, none of the style attributes from my CSS file are detected. Does `nextElementSibling` only detect inline styles? I'm sure I can think of other ways to achieve this but I want to know why `nextElementSibling` is selecting the proper element but not detecting the style properly?

EDIT:

CSS

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1fff8;
}
```

Comment: *When I select all div with the collapsible class...* I don't see any elements in your posted code with a class of `collapsible` except your `button`. There is `outer-collapsible`, but not `collapsible`.

Comment: Please also post the relevant CSS that you believe should be applied to the `div` when it is shown.

Comment: `nextElementSibling` has nothing whatsoever to do with styles. It is about gaining a reference to an element. If you styles aren't working, we have to look at the way you are setting up the element and the CSS you've written for that element.

Comment: JS elements style attribute get's the inline styles not styles from a css file

Comment: Try: `window.getComputedStyle(collapsibles[i].nextElementSibling)['display']` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue of `nextElementSibling`, it's an issue of how you detect CSS styles in the first place.

`.style` can only be used to read the contents of the `style` attribute, e.g. `<div style="color: red"></div>`.

In order to read the "actual" styles, you probably want [.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

From the mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#:%7E:text=The%20style%20property%20is%20used,the%20element%27s%20inline%20style%20attribute.)

> The style property is not useful for completely learning about the
> styles applied on the  element, since it represents only the CSS
> declarations set in the element's inline style  attribute, not those
> that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the
>
> section, or external style sheets. To get the values of all CSS
> properties for an  element you should use Window.getComputedStyle()
> instead.

So you can't use the style attribute to access styles in stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Styles can be applied to elements in a variety of places and by a variety of [`selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (id, class, position, etc.). Depending on where and how you set up your selector, it has a higher or lower ["specificity"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than others. Styles set directly inline with the HTML have the highest specificity and cannot be overridden by other styles. As a result, they restrict your ability to have flexible code and are generally discouraged.

When you use the [`.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) in JavaScript, you are working with the inline style of the element.

Instead, it's best to work with CSS classes and apply/remove them as needed. The [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API in JavaScript makes this very simple:

```js
let collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');

document.querySelector(".collapsible").addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* The show/hide will be handled by applying/removing this class */
.hidden { display:none; }

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1fff8;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-collapsible'>
      <button type='button' class='collapsible'>Targets and Victims</button>
      <div class='content hidden'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```